# Is there any priority condition between gesture methods (Pan Gesture and Swipe Gesture)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am developing an application where I have used the Pan Gesture as well as Swipe Gesture. So every time I do the Swipe Gesture but the method from the Pan Gesture is always getting called and Swipe Gesture method is not getting called.

Is there any priority between all the gesture method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call them in parallel by implementing the following method of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm using "https://github.com/XavierDK/XDKAirMenu" and also am using swipe gesture in one of my controller so this delegate is not working for me

Comment: I tried this with the NSPanGestureRecognizer and the NSClickGesture recognizer and it did not work for me. My NSButton click only get through about 25% of the time unless I disable the pan recognizer.

Answer (score 9):

There is a property on the `UIGestureRecognizer` class called "cancelsTouchesInView" which defaults to `YES`. This will cause any pending gestures to be canceled. The Pan gesture is getting recognized first since it does not need to have a "touch up" event, so it cancels the Swipe gesture.

If you want both gestures to be recognized, try adding:

`[yourPanGestureInstance setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`

Comment: thank You for The answering But This Method Still don't Identify the Swipe Gesture

Comment: I have Also Try The  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer Method         Within the UIGestureRecognizer.H file

Answer (score 3):

**Give priority to swipe**

You can give priority to a `UIGestureRecognizer` with the  `require(toFail:)` method.

```
@IBOutlet var myPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet var mySwipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

myPanGesture.require(toFail: mySwipeGestureRecognizer)
```

Now your *pan* will only execute if your *swipe* fails.

---

**Use *pan* for everything**

If the *swipe* and *pan* gesture recognizers don't play nicely with this setup, you can roll all of your logic into the *pan* gesture recognizer for more control.

```
let minHeight: CGFloat = 100
let maxHeight: CGFloat = 700
let swipeVelocity: CGFloat = 500
var previousTranslationY: CGFloat = 0

@IBOutlet weak var cardHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func didPanOnCard(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let panGesture = sender as? UIPanGestureRecognizer else { return }

    let gestureEnded = bool(panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended)
    let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: self.view)

    if gestureEnded && abs(velocity.y) > swipeVelocity {
        handlePanOnCardAsSwipe(withVelocity: velocity.y)
    } else {
        handlePanOnCard(panGesture)
    }
} 

func handlePanOnCard(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self.view)
    let translationYDelta = translation.y - previousTranslationY

    if abs(translationYDelta) < 1 { return } // ignore small changes

    let newCardHeight = cardHeightConstraint.constant - translationYDelta

    if newCardHeight > minHeight && newCardHeight < maxHeight {
        cardHeightConstraint.constant = newCardHeight
        previousTranslationY = translation.y
    }

    if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        previousTranslationY = 0
    }
}

func handlePanOnCardAsSwipe(withVelocity velocity: CGFloat) {
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        dismissCard() // implementation not shown
    } else {
        maximizeCard() // implementation not shown
    }
}
```

Here's a demo of the above code in action.

[image]